# How to i can keep selected tag in select2 when i change element options

Tags: jquery-select2

```js
// js i call select2

$('#select-user-multiple').select2({
            closeOnSelect: false,
            tags: true,
            allowClear: true
        });

// my code to get list users by select organization and suborganization

 $('#slc-UserOrganization').change(function(){
            var parentId = $('#slc-UserOrganization').val();
            var subOrgId = $('#slc-UserSubOrganization').val();
            getListUserForSendEmail(parentId, subOrgId);
            if (parentId != -1) {
                getListSubOrganizationEmail(parentId);
            } else {
                $('#slc-UserSubOrganization').find('option').remove();
            }
        });

$('#slc-UserSubOrganization').change(function(){
            var parentId = parseInt($('#slc-UserOrganization').val(), 10);
            var subOrgId = parseInt($('#slc-UserSubOrganization').val(), 10);
            getListUserForSendEmail(parentId, subOrgId);
        });


function getListUserForSendEmail(unitId, partId) {
        $('#select-user-multiple').find('option').attr("disabled", true);
        // $('#select-user-multiple').find('option').attr("style", "display:none");
        // $('select2-select-user-multiple-results').find('li').hide();

        $.ajax({
        url : URL_vBooking,
        jsonp : "jsoncallback",
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        data : {
            _f : 122,
            unitId: unitId,
            partId: partId,
            start: 0,
            limit: 1000,
            ownerId: communityIdGlobal,
            communityId: communityIdGlobal
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if(response.success){
                $.each(response.object, function(key, value){
                    // var checkboxHtml = '';
                    // var user_community = value.community;
                    // var attendeeInfo = '{"email":"' + value.email + '", "communityId":' + value.communityId + ', "name":"' + user_community.name + '", "partId":' + value.partId + ', "unitId":' + value.unitId + '}';
                    // checkboxHtml += '<option user_id="'+ value.communityId + '" value="'+ attendeeInfo +'">'+ user_community.name +'</option>'
                      
                    // $('select#select-user-multiple').append(checkboxHtml);
                    // console.log(checkboxHtml);

                    var checkboxHtml = '';
                    var user_community = value.community;
                    var attendeeInfo = '{"email":"' + value.email + '", "communityId":' + value.communityId + ', "name":"' + user_community.name + '", "partId":' + value.partId + ', "unitId":' + value.unitId + '}';

                    checkboxHtml += "<option value='"+ attendeeInfo +"' user_id='"+ value.communityId + "'>"+ value.name +"</option>";
                      
                    $('select#select-user-multiple').append(checkboxHtml);
                });
            }
        },
        error: function(response){
            console.log("getListUserForSendEmail() ==> error:\n" + JSON.stringify(response));
        }
        });
    }
```

```css
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41798617/edit#
```

```html
// my modal
<div class="modal fade" id="modalBooking" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalBooking">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content" style="width: 800px;">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Thêm Ngư?i Tham D?</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="modal-body-header">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12">

                                <select id="slc-UserOrganization" class="form-control input-sm col-sm-4" style="text-align: center; width: 35%">
                                    <option value="-1">-----------Đơn V?-----------</option>
                                    <!-- append các đơn v? vào t?i đây -->
                                </select>
                                <div class="input-sm col-sm-4" style="width: 5%">
                                    
                                </div>
                            
                                <select id="slc-UserSubOrganization" class="form-control input-sm col-sm-4" style="text-align: center; width: 30%">
                                    <option value="-1">---Ph?ng Ban---</option>
                                    <!-- append các ph?ng ban vào t?i đây khi select đơn v?-->
                                </select>

                                <div class="input-sm col-sm-4" style="width: 15%; padding: 0px 10px;">
                                    <button class="btn-add-suborganization" onClick="addSuborganization();" style="background-color: #3c8dbc; border-color: #367fa9; color: #fff; height: 100%;">Ch?n Ph?ng</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                            <div>
                                <label for="id_label_multiple">Danh sách thành viên</label>  
                            </div>
                              <select class="js-example-basic-multiple js-states form-control" id="select-user-multiple" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%">
                                 
                              </select>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Quay l?i</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

hi everyone!
I'm using select2 bootraps to select and show multi selected users for sending mail to them. When i change 1 other dropdown, elements option in select2 change. And, selected tags i chose before will be removed auto. Is there anyway to i keep them? please tell me. Many thanks.

first, i choose some option.

Then, i change other dropdown, elements option will change and selected tags are removed. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNNyX.png

Comment: Hi Chien, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the lines about asking questions here.
In a nutshell, you should be posting the code that you have tried so far so that community can help you out!

Comment: yes, thank you so much. it's my mistake. i 've just edited my post. can you give a help?